# index.js converted to index.ts but seeing strange errors which I can't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This is my code:

```js
import 'core-js';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from 'src/store/configureStore';
import createRootReducer from 'src/store/rootReducer';
import App from './Main/App';
import './index.css';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const { store } = configureStore({ history, initialState: {} });

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App history={history} />
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./Main/App', () => {
    return render();
  });
  module.hot.accept('./store/rootReducer', () => {
    store.replaceReducer(createRootReducer(history));
  });
}
```

I'm getting errors like: 
- Error TypeScript  '>' expected.   22:17
Which is complaining about:

```
<AppContainer>
```

and here: 
- the left hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type any

```
<App history={history} />
```

I don't have 'strict' set in my config.
Any advice on this. thanks

Comment: What do you have processing the JSX?

Comment: The proper file extension is `.tsx`, and you need compiler support for that

Comment: brilliant. I knew it was something simple. Thanks